# Remove empty items from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I managed to combine JSON files and with the help of StackOverflow also removing specific items (name) from my JSON. I would like to remove empty items (value) from my JSON file to to reduce the size of it. I try removing empty items from an array but can't manage to make the code work. Here is the code without removing items.

Example JSON: https://pastebin.com/4QsRn32d

```
$sets = array();
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($data as $key => $innerObject) {
        if (isset(
                $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
                $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
                $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 3']
        )) {
            unset(
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 3']
            );
        }
    }
    $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
    $sets = array_merge($sets, $data);
}

$new = json_encode($sets, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
echo $new;

$fp = fopen('combined_en.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $new);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: can you share the sample json

Comment: Here is the example JSON: https://pastebin.com/4QsRn32d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one way to go at it is using `array_filter` function. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> ```
> array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )
> ```
>
> If no `callback` is supplied, all entries of `array` equal to `FALSE` will be removed.

Now, if you go down to the same documentation, you can see a [sample recursive implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87581):

```
<?php
function array_filter_recursive($input)
{
    foreach ($input as &$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
        }
    }

    return array_filter($input);
}
```

With these in mind, we can write:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$filteredData = array_filter_recursive($data);
$filteredJson = json_encode($filteredData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Posted my working code below.

Answer (score 1):

Final working code. Thanks to @Jomoos.

```
function array_filter_recursive($input)
{
    foreach ($input as &$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
        }
    }

    return array_filter($input);
}

$sets = array();
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($data as $key => $innerObject) {
        if (isset(
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 3']
        )) {
            unset(
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 3']
            );
        }
    }
    $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
    $sets = array_merge($sets, $data);
    $filteredData = array_filter_recursive($sets);
}


$new = json_encode($filteredData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
echo $new;

$fp = fopen('combined_en.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $new);
fclose($fp);
```